# how to access spring property placeholder generated properties object?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

We are using property placeholder configurer in multiple apps(12-15) and would like to access final properties object prepared by propertly place holder to see what properties and its values being used by that app. In each app we want to have one page with ready only values displayed since each app has multiple propeeties file and environment properties so would like to see final state of that properties object.

Note: we are using spring 4.1 with spring web mvc and spring batch 3.x

Comment: Want to show all properties(name/value) in single jsp page for viewing only. Dont want to change those props during runtime.